# Prevent AdaBoost from overfitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, overfitting, adaboost

I am doing [this challenge on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic) and I am trying to use AdaBoost from scikit-learn.

My code is like this:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
ada=AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=50,random_state=0,learning_rate=0.01)
prediction = ada.fit(train_input, train_labels).predict(test_input)
```

Here, `train_input`, and `test_input` are of the form:

```
   Pclass  Sex  Age_band  Family_Size  Fare_cat
0       3    0         2            0         0
1       3    1         2            1         0
2       2    0         3            0         1
3       3    0         1            0         1
4       3    1         1            2         1
```

while `train_labels` and `test_labels` are of the form:

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
```

For some reason, with this model the accuracy is `1`:

```
labels=test_labels.iloc[:, 1].values
print('The accuracy is',metrics.accuracy_score(prediction, labels))
```

However, when I submit the predictions, the accuracy is only around `0.77`.

Any idea why the accuracy on my test data is `1`?
Am I not using `AdaBoostClassifier` correctly and it's overfitting?